# mcustomscrollbar duplicate scroll bar

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, click, scrollbar

i have a problem,
I create div dynamically, each div has a different id
if I try to close a div and open it again, the scroll bar is duplicated
how can I do to prevent this?

```
$('.open_desc').click(function(){
 var id = $(this).attr('id');
 $("#desc"+id).fadeIn(1200);
 $("#desc"+id).mCustomScrollbar({
                             mouseWheel:false,
                            scrollButtons:{
                             enable:true
                              }
                              });
      });


 $('.close_desc').click(function(){
  var id = $(this).attr('id');
  $("#desc"+id).fadeOut(1200);
 });
```

thanks

Answer (score 0):

Mmm, i have the same problem. It depends how you call that method. If don't use ajax you can call

```
$("#desc"+id).mCustomScrollbar({
         mouseWheel:false,
         scrollButtons:{
         enable:true
                    }
     });
  });
```

in your $(document).ready function then when you call:

```
  $('.open_desc').click(function(){
            var id = $(this).attr('id');
            $("#desc"+id).fadeIn(1200);
            $("#desc"+id).mCustomScrollbar("update"); // this prevent double calling
            var id = $(this).attr('id');
            $("#desc"+id).fadeOut(1200);
 });
```

If you use ajax technology with jquery .load() is the same.
If you use ajax technology from http request it becomes more difficult and i'm trying to solve.

Hope this helps.